# Django model TextField not rendering

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I've been trying to render the contents of a TextField onto my HTML page, but it's the only thing that just refuses to render. Could it be a problem with the inheritance of that model?

Here is my model:

```
class Section(models.Model):
    order_id = models.IntegerField()
    SECTION_TYPE_CHOICES = (('reg', 'regular'),
                        ('not', 'note'),
                        )
    section_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=5,
        choices=SECTION_TYPE_CHOICES,
        default='reg',
    )

class TextSection(Section):
    contents = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=5000)

class Post(models.Model):
    post_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    belongs_to = models.ForeignKey('Story')
    order_id = models.IntegerField()
    contents = models.ManyToManyField(Section, blank=True)
```

and the template

```
{% extends 'stories/base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    {{ post.belongs_to.title }} | {{ post.title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <!-- Story Information -->
    <div>
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <p>by {{ post.author }} on {{  post.published_date }}</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Post Contents -->
    <div>
        {% for section in post.contents.all %}
            <div>
<!--------- Part that does not render --------->
                <p>{{ section.contents|safe }}</p>
<!--------- Part that does not render --------->
                {{ section.order_id }}

            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

It always renders the section.order_id but never renders the section.contents

Thanks in advance for any advice.

EDIT: Ended up removing polymorphism and just expanding my Section model to include various contents.

Answer (score 0):

`Post.contents` points to the Section model, not TextSection; Section itself doesn't have a `contents` field. If you need this, you should point your many-to-many field directly to TextSection.

Comment: If I add a contents field to Section, will TextSection overwrite that? I want the capability to add an ImageSection or VideoSection in the future.

Comment: The idea was to have contents contain different kinds of sections, if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I ended up scrapping the polymorphism and just expanding my Section model.